# Realtime chart JS in Java obtaining the data from a sensor ;Chart.js: Failed to create chart: can't acquire context from the given item

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I am trying to to plot a realtime chart using chart.js. The sesnor gives real time data which is updated to be plotted on the chart. I have followed the steps provided in the documentation in order to add or update data but its showing me the error :Chart.js:**Failed to create chart: can't acquire context from the given item**, **[check image please](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UgG79.jpg)** 
I am implementing a new class (makeChart) with a constructor where the chart objects and the chart instance are defined inside the constructor. Following comes the addData method in the same class and this method is called in the refresh class (another class called Dashbaord). AddData method is suppose to update data in the same format given in the documentation.This is all in a java file called dashboard.js. The canvas where the chart is to be plotted is in a separate HTML file called dashbaord.html.

The console is showing that ctx and canvas are equal to null.

When the (this.testChart.update();) is decommented, an error shows at fou different lines:

1-  this.makeChart = new makeChart;

2-  that.makeChart.addData(result.particles.PM0_3); // at refresh

3-  this.testChart = new Chart (ctx,{  // at chart instance

4-  this.testChart.update();  // update way provided by chart.js

Commenting the this.testChart.update(); gives error at **this.makeChart = new makeChart;** and at **this.testChart = new Chart (ctx,{**   which is the main reason why the chart is not plotted.

I am suspecting the error has something to do with the connection between the two classes because when I try to plot the chart inside the first class it works but without the realtime data from sensor and upated time. I am going to post the java code below along with the dashboard.html lines to plot chart.

Looking forward for your help guys and sorry for the long post here. I appreciate it...

dashboard.js code:

```
class Dashboard {
   constructor(jsonRPC, auth){

    this.jsonRPC = jsonRPC;
    this.auth = auth;
    this.updateInterval = 10;                //every 10 seconds
    this.makeChart = new makeChart;

}

run() {

    var that = this;
    that.jsonRPC.call('extension.get', {'select':'data'}).then(function (result) {

    //Initialize Device Infos
    $('#tab_info').load('html/dashboard.html #content', function(){
    $(".GaugeMeter").gaugeMeter();// Initialize GaugeMeter plugin

        //Start Data Refresh Cycle
        that.refresh();
    });
  });
}

refresh() { 
    var that = this;
    that.jsonRPC.call('extension.get', {'select':'data'}).then(function (result) {
    that.makeChart.addData(result.particles.PM0_3);

    });

    //Wait 1 seconds before checking state
    setTimeout(function(){
       that.refresh();
    }, this.updateInterval * 1000);
 }
```

}

```
 class makeChart{
    constructor(){
    //Chart Objects
        var ctx =  'testChart';
        //var ctx = document.getElementById('testChart');


    //Chart configurations
        var commonOptions = {
        scales: {
            xAxes: [{
                type: 'time',
                distribution: 'series',
                time:  {
                displayFormats:
                {
                second: 'h:mm:ss a'
                },
                unit:'second'
                }
            }],
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero:true
                }
            }]
        },
        legend: {display: false},
        tooltips:{
            enabled: true
        }
    };

    //Chart instance
        this.testChart = new Chart (ctx,{
        type: 'line',
        data: {
        labels: [],                             //x axis
        datasets: [{
            label: "Particles Number10",          //change for each conc and part no
            data: [],                            //y axis
            fill: false,
            borderColor: '#343e9a',
            borderWidth: 1
        }]
     },
        options: Object.assign({}, commonOptions, {
        title:{
            display: true,
            text: "Particles Number10",          //change for each conc and part no
            fontSize: 18
            },
            maintainAspectRatio: false,
            responsive: false,
        })
     });
    console.log(this.testChart);

  };                                             //end of constructor


    addData (data) {

        if(data) {
    var today = new Date();
    var time =  today.getDate() +'/'+ (today.getMonth()+1)+ '/'+ today.getFullYear() +' '+ 
    today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds();

    var chart_numberElements = 60;
    var chart_updateCount = 0;

    this.testChart.data.labels.push(time);
    this.testChart.data.datasets.push(data);

        if(chart_updateCount > chart_numberElements){
            this.testChart.data.labels.shift();
            this.testChart.data.datasets.shift();
        } else chart_updateCount++;

        //this.testChart.destroy();
        //this.testChart.update();

      }
    };
};
```

dashboard.html where the canvas is called is like follows:

```html
 <div class="modal-body">
   <canvas id="testChart" width="800" height="400"></canvas>
   </div>
```

All what I get instead of the chart is what is shown in image here [chart seen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5PTJM.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Chart.js requires a `<canvas>` element at initialization. You seem to have known this at some point as you have the right code, but it's commented out and replaced with a string:

```
var ctx =  'testChart';
//var ctx = document.getElementById('testChart');
```

Simply reverse these to make it work:

```
//var ctx =  'testChart';
var ctx = document.getElementById('testChart');
```

Of course, you'll need to ensure the `<canvas>` element is present in the DOM at runtime.

Comment: whenever I reverse it like you suggested, I get ctx = null. I have tried that before and it is not working.

Comment: In the documentation they mention that there are different ways in which the canvas element is initialized ;

Comment: If it's `null` then the element is not present in the DOM. Ensure you run the javascript _after_ DOM is ready.

Comment: Is the only way to add the element in DOM is one of the four mentioned ways in documentation?

Comment: None of the four ways _add_ the element - they only access it. You need to add the element yourself, either statically in your HTML or dynamically via javascript. But your code snippet for `dashboard.html` shows a `<canvas>` element with the correct `id`. So the problem is probably _when_ you run the javascript. If it runs before the DOM is initialised, the element doesn't exist at runtime.

Comment: yeah the javascript runs before the DOM element is loaded. Will try to use window.onload = function () and see if it fix the issue.

Comment: the window.onload fixes the ctx = null problem but the **( this.testChart = new Chart (ctx,{  )**  is showing an error as the addData updating the data to the new Chart is separated due to the windowonload.